# Adding elements to last element of array

Tags: php, arrays

If I have the following array. What would be the best way to add a element to `list[]` for the last element of `$myArray[]`?  Note that `list[]` has numerical indexes (i.e. not associative). Thanks!

```
$myArray[] = array( 'name' => 'hello', 'list' => array() );
```

Comment: Your question is a tad unclear. Could you post an example of what your result should look like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $myArray is not associative

```
array_push($myArray[count($myArray)-1]['list'], 'new element');
```

or

```
$myArray[count($myArray)-1]['list'][] = 'new element';
```

with this method you change the position of the array pointer.

Comment: Yes, this will likely work.  Didn't know if there was a cleaner solution using end()

Comment: when you use end you get a copy of the last value, not a reference. So if you change the value it does not effect the array. If you use `end` you have to call it at first, then use `key` to get the key of the last element and can then modify the array. If `$myArray` is not associative you might want to do that.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
$last = array_pop($myArray); // remove last element of array
$last['list'][] = "new element"; // add element to array
$myArray[] = $last; // add changed last element again
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$myArray[count($myArray)-1]['list'][]="something to go in 'list' array";//this shall append 
//to the second dimension array with keyname 'list'
```

Comment: Instead of $myArray[0], it would need to point to the last element of $myArray, not 0.

Comment: Gotcha.  Same solution as clenfort.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a more  beautiful way (in my opinion):

```
$ref = &$myArray[];
$ref['list'][] = 'new item'
```

As you can see $ref - is reference to the last element of $myArray, so you can change the last element by changing $ref;

Answer (score -3):

`array_push` function do that.

```
array_push()
```

Comment: After the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) this has the same effect as `$array[] = $var;` which he has used in his code already. So I don't think he's searching for this.